Elasticsearch custom engine with laravel scout returns null
So i have intergrated elasticsearch to my laravel app and everyhting works fine when i search manually , it does the indexes and everything its just that whenever i use the engine search() methode it always returns null and i don't know why, take a look:
public function search(Builder $builder)
    {
        // Get the search query from the builder
        $query = $builder->query;
        // Define the Elasticsearch search parameters
        $params = [
            'index' => 'products_index', // Use the specified index or search in all indices
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => [
                        'title' => $query
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];


        // Perform the search using the Elasticsearch client
        $response = $this->elasticsearch->search($params);

        // Extract the hits from the response
        $hits = $response['hits']['hits'];

        // Check if the hits contain the expected _source field
        if (empty($hits)) {
            Log::warning('No hits found in the search response');
            return [];
        }

        // Map the search results to Eloquent models
        $models = [];
        foreach ($hits as $hit) {
            // Assuming each document in Elasticsearch corresponds to a single Eloquent model
            if (isset($hit['_source'])) {
                $models[] = $this->map($builder, $hit, $builder->model);

            } else {
                Log::error('Missing _source field in search result', ['hit' => $hit]);
            }

        }
        dump($models);
        return $models;
    }

public function map(Builder $builder, $results, $model)
    {

        /*$modelInstance = null;*/
        // Check if the '_source' key exists in the results
        if ($results && isset($results['_source'])) {
            Log::warning('every thing seem fine');
            // Get the primary key name of the model
            $keyName = $model->getKeyName();

            // Create a new instance of the model
            $modelInstance = $model->newInstance();

            // Set the raw attributes of the model from the Elasticsearch source
            $modelInstance->setRawAttributes($results['_source']);

            // Set the primary key attribute of the model
            $modelInstance->setAttribute($keyName, $results['_id']);
            return $modelInstance;

        }else Log::error('Missing _source field in search results', ['results' => $results]);

    }

whenever i use Product::search($query)->get();
as you can see in my search() methode i have wrote a dump() above the return.
the dump($model) works and shows the result but the return is null
I mean is there anything im missing?
p.s
and for some reasone even when i empty the search methode, when i search, the engine runs the map() methode!!!!
i have searched alot and used logs and AIs but so far nothing.

Can you clarify "the dump($model) works and shows the result but the return is null". Does it mean that when you call dump $model is not null but then somehow you think what is getting returned in the following line is null?

@imotov yes that is correct, and i found out what was the problem, for some reason when you use laravel scout for searching it goes to your search() method and after that uses what you have returned in search() as $results inside map(Builder $builder, $results, $model) and runs map() automatically then your search response will be recieved from what map() returns .
